# VSCode customize window border

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'd like to add a subtle border around VSCode so multiple open windows don't blend together.

I've looked through the Theme Color API Reference but didn't spot any relevant setting:
https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color

I'm using the Material Theme and would like to add a border, something like this

```
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "[Material Theme Darker]": {
            // These settings work:
            "editor.foreground": "#f1f1f1", // regular text color
            // "editor.background": "#ff0000"
            // "sideBar.background": "#ff0000",

            //I'd like something like this, but it DOESN'T WORK:
            "window.border": "#444444"
        }
    },
```

I would like for each VSCode window to have a border of 1 pixel, so that when two windows overlap they're not blending together.

For example, here is one VSCode window on top of another, but it's hard to tell where one ends and the other begins:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

VS Code 1.40 adds [two new theme colors for this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/82781):

- `window.activeBorder` — When the window is active
- `window.inactiveBorder` — When the window is inactive

```
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "[Material Theme Darker]": {

            "window.activeBorder": "#444444"
        }
    }
```

Comment: The October 2019 release of VS Code includes support for `window.activeBorder` and `window.inactiveBorder` https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_40#_themable-window-border

Comment: Is this working on Windows (11) at the moment.  I thought I saw an issue about it...  I can't see any difference no matter what color I try.

Comment: Looks like this no longer works in WIndows 10.

Answer (score 6):

Sadly this is no longer possible.  Support for window.activeBorder and window.InactiveBorder has been officially widthdrawn, as of Visual Studio Code 1.71.x

See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/160159

Comment: 

Comment: Added to that in VS Code on my PC I didn't get the default Windows 11 app borders, even after removing the window.activeBorder and window.inactiveBorder options. In fact I had no border at all. Found a solution here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/165399

In the VS Code settings: window.titleBarStyle: "native"